# Error: glBufferData using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, opengl-es, chromium

I am having this error when the app is trying to get data from internet:

**E/chromium(5891): [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(313)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xaeeced60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command**

The app is using cordova and android. This problem only occurs with Android 5.1 and I don't know why is this happening because the app works with all other devices.

Comment: Show the relevant source code. Otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: waiting an answer on this too